# multi touch gestures on elementary OS 6 Odin partially not working

Tags: touchpad, gesture

I have tried a live OS and the 4 fingers have partial issues with them, they do not toggle maximizing for example and bunch of other features, but the 3 fingers (vertical, horizontal & pinching) is working fine, I thought that maybe the touchpad is not triggered when I touch using 4 fingers but it works in some cases (like switching between workspaces).

The bottom line, is this only happening because i am on a live OS and it will get resolved when i install the system?

What if I want to utilize more options that the built-in gestures does not provide, such as:

1. 4 fingers pinch-in to close the window.
2. 4 fingers swipe down to minimize the window.
3. 3 fingers swipe down to minimize all windows at once.
4. 3 fingers swipe right to go to next tab.
5. 3 fingers swipe left to go back (<kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd>)).
6. 3 fingers rotation for tiling to right or left.

Can I map custom keyboard shortcuts without breaking the built-in gestures (like disabling some features)?

Update 1: My Laptop is Lenovo Legion Y530

Comment: Some of this will depend on the model and sensitivity level of the touchpad. Can you update your question to include the brand and model of your computer? This will make it much easier to offer specific information 